# Is it important to i18n your img alt attributes?

Tags: html, internationalization

For those of you who i18n, do you i18n the `alt` attribute on your `img` tags?  Is it really worth it?

Comment: If only life were so simple! But we don't wake up to a decision tree like `if (respectUsers) { makeEverythingPerfect(); } else { /* just be lazy */}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I guess if you wanted your site to be truly i18n'd, then yes.

It might be an extra headache, but some vision impaired people out there are thanking you :)

Also, are you using i18n JavaScript strings too?

Comment: Very true.  508 compliance requires this http://bit.ly/d3I1wV (link to 508 compliance site talking about alt tags)

Comment: @Adam - no need to use URL shorteners